# How to handle SameSite attribute in Express with incompatible clients?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, express-session, samesite

Chrome is changing the default value of `SameSite` cookie attribute from `None` to `Lax` as of its version 80. My site is embedded to another site using an iframe and the login session of my site is handled by `express-session`.

For new browsers the solution is just to set the session cookie to `SameSite=None; Secure` which `express-session` already supports. However, some [clients are incompatible](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/incompatible-clients) for the `SameSite` attribute and would stop working.

[One proposed solution](https://web.dev/samesite-cookie-recipes/) to the problem is to use two cookies, one for new clients and one for the old incompatible clients:

```
Set-cookie: session-id=value; SameSite=None; Secure
Set-cookie: session-id-legacy=value; Secure
```

Is it possible to use the proposed two-cookie solution to the problem or is there a better way in `express-session` to also provide support to old incompatible browsers?

Comment: Adding this as a comment, since it's not really a complete answer. I would suggest looking at creating some kind of middleware to coalesce the cookies before they reach the `express-session` handler. You can see how I'm doing this kind of thing in a Cloudflare worker here: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/cloudflare-worker/cloudflare-worker.md

Comment: Thanks, that might be the best approach. It probably needs to be a wrapper middleware since the cookies need to be handled both before they reach the `express-session` but also after the `express-session` has set the cookie for a new session.